# How to export powershell output to excel

Tags: powershell, export

I have found the custom lists in a particular site and I want to print the names to Excel. How do I do it?

Comment: You can try using steps in below URL: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/137203-create-an-excel-file-from-within-powershell

Comment: Script Saves numbers as text, would be nice to see one that doesn't convert integers and floats to text

Answer (score 5):

Use the following Command:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb SiteUrl
$spWeb.Lists | select Title | Export-CSV c:\Lists.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe the output from your command to an .csv file:

```
FileToExecute.ps1 | Out-File C:\output.csv
```

Make sure you in your script file uses `Write-Output`and not `Write-Host` when printing your output.

Answer (score 1):

You can export any output of the powershell to a CSV. This is a built in function.

[Export-CSV](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works:

```
Install-Module importexcel
```

If it works, then after that you can use `export-excel` command.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna use the Export-Csv parameter. I also found this easy example.

[SharePoint list to .csv file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5acece21-62eb-4e07-b348-4fe184df4a38/sharepoint-list-to-csv-file)

[Export-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

```
$MyWeb = WebUrl 
$MyList = MyWeb.Lists["ListName"] 
$MyItems = $MyList.Items
$MyItems | Select Fields.. | Export-Csv -path C:\example\excel.csv
$MyWeb.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Export-CSV as usual way we can export the SharePoint list items to a csv file, and using the below code we can convert the particular csv file to excel file:

```
### Set input and output path
$inputCSV = "C:\somefolder\input.csv"
$outputXLSX = "C:\somefolder\output.xlsx"

### Create a new Excel Workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

### Build the QueryTables.Add command
### QueryTables does the same as when clicking "Data » From Text" in Excel
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

### Set the delimiter (, or ;) according to your regional settings
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

### Set the format to delimited and text for every column
### A trick to create an array of 2s is used with the preceding comma
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

### Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

### Save & close the Workbook as XLSX. Change the output extension for Excel 2003
$Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX,51)
$excel.Quit()
```

Reference URL:

[How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell)

Note:

- There is no direct inbuilt function to export in excel using PowerShell as like Export-CSV, so first we need to export to csv file, then we have to convert that file to excel.